# Permissionset issue in Apex

Tags: apex, visualforce, permissions

When I try to look for a permission set associated with a particular user in a controller class,  I am seeing a permissionset with name X00ed0000000TTlfAAG and ID 0PSd0000000XJ15 related to the user. (I searched for this permission set I am unable to find how this is related to the user).

[image]
I tried from DEV console and I get nothing back too:

Execute Anonymous: list users_info = [SELECT PermissionSet.id,AssigneeId FROM PermissionSetAssignment WHERE Id =:'0PSd0000000XJ15'];

```
11:20:49.019 (19656000)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[1]|Aggregations:0|select PermissionSet.id, AssigneeId from PermissionSetAssignment where Id = :tmpVar1
11:20:49.032 (32737000)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[1]|Rows:0
```

I am a sys admin in my org , When I try to copy paste this URL I get insufficient priviledges. I checked the Recyle bin too , nothing there to delete.

Is this a bug , the ID seems to be a valid permset ID.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the PermissionSet IsOwnedByProfile as you can tell from the name (00e is the Profile keyprefix)

set permission set details here: 
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/sforce_api_objects_permissionset.htm

your query will never return a value because the PermissionSetAssignment record ids start with 0Pa

[SELECT PermissionSet.id,AssigneeId FROM PermissionSetAssignment WHERE **PermissionSet.id =:'0PSd0000000XJ15'**

**UPDATE**
here's the query that solved the question

[select Id, Name[,......] from PermissionSet where Id IN (select Id from PermissionSetAssignment where AssigneeId =: USER_ID_PROVIDED_BY_THE_USER)]

Comment: System.debug(System.LoggingLevel.Error,Id.valueOf('0PSd0000000XJ15').getSObjectType()); // Output: PermissionSet

You can determine the type of SObject an ID represents to confirm problems like this.

Comment: why do I see this related to my user Id, is it because the permission set is related to the profile and not to my user Id.I am still confused on why I see the permission set related to my ID when I dont see it through the UI?

Comment: @rao I suppose you dont see it because it is owned by a profile and is linked via User.ProfileId relationship (kinda tricky) btw. updated the reponse to make it clearer

Comment: can you please get on chat, if you have some time to spare :/ http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4337/salesforce

Comment: How do I know what permission sets are related to a profile from the UI perspective , I always thought permission sets are entities that can be related only to a user since they have a view user option and not a view profiles,I can associated a permission set to a user can I associate a permission set to a specific profile too ?

Comment: @rao am online. have to run in 20 min, so half past

Comment: To answer your question - you cannot see the permission set parented by a profile in the UI - it's only accessible via the API. We did this on purpose. The fact that there's a permission set underlying every profile is an implementation detail we wanted to hide from admins but it became advantageous to expose this detail to developers (http://www.salesforcehacker.com/2013/01/using-soql-to-determine-your-forcecom.html).

Answer (score 5):

There are two categories of PermissionSets that are stored in the `PermissionSet` object:

- **standalone Permission Sets** (have `IsOwnedByProfile = false`)
- **Permission Sets owned by Profiles** (have `IsOwnedByProfile = true`)

**Standalone Permission Sets** are the ones you are used to; they appear in the list of PermissionSets when you click on 'Permission Sets' from the Setup menu, and you can assign them to users using the `PermissionSetAssignment` object. You can Create, Edit, and Delete Standalone Permission Sets. They are NOT associated with any particular Profile.

**Permission Sets owned by Profiles** are the strange ones you are seeing above that start with `X00`. Under the hood, each Salesforce `Profile` record has an associated `PermissionSet` record, which links together all of the Object, Field, App, User, and Setup Entity Access permissions that define the Profile. These do NOT appear in the Setup menu's "Permission Sets" area, because they are represented by their corresponding Profiles. Moreover, they are NOT assigned to users, at least not directly --- the `ProfileId` field on the user record is the only link that connects you to the associated Profile's corresponding PermissionSet.

In your class above, you should filter out the PermissionSets owned by Profiles by adding `IsOwnedByProfile = true` to your SOQL WHERE clause:

```
List<PermissionSet> standalonePermSets = [
   select Id,Name from PermissionSet where IsOwnedByProfile = false
];
```

Comment: Awesome, I never knew there was a hidden area under the hood , crystal clear explanation.